# How I can get past this error: "BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default"?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, compiler-errors

Hello I am trying to get the [tabletojson](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tabletojson) package working in my React project.

Here is the main error I keep getting:

```
Compiled with problems:

ERROR in ./node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/dist/source/index.js 9:15-30

Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'util' in './node_modules/@szmarczak/http-timer/dist/source'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "util": require.resolve("util/") }'
    - install 'util'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "util": false }
```

I haven't moved my node modules folder and all the other packages can be found without any problem.
Literally all I am trying to do so far is run the [example from the npm package page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tabletojson#remote-converturl):

```
'use strict';

const tabletojson = require('tabletojson').Tabletojson;

tabletojson.convertUrl(
    'https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISO_639-1_codes',
    function(tablesAsJson) {
        console.log(tablesAsJson[1]);
    }
);
```

That particular example works fine on [Runkit](https://npm.runkit.com/tabletojson) if I remove `'use strict'` but removing `'use strict'` doesn't help resolve the error when running this locally.

Comment: The solution is already in the question you asked. Did you try doing as the error says and configuring a polyfill for the node.js core module `util`?

Comment: Yes I tried configuring it a few different ways, including adding a fallback to the webpck config file. Since posting this question I tracked down an [open issue](https://github.com/maugenst/tabletojson/issues/63) on the package GitHub and it looks like there is no appetite to fix it.

Comment: It seems it's waiting for a user to response on the issue...